# Check if the user has attached any file

Tags: 2010, javascript, form, attachments, user-accounts

When I open(edit) some item in a list I want to check with JavaScript if the user has attached any file in my Edit Form...

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide some more context here... I understand you want to check if a user attached a file, but what are you attempting to do with the results? Are you looking to use javascript to check the edit form before an item is first submitted? Are you looking to check if items that were submitted have an attachment?

Comment: yes I want to check with JavaScript....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
            var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
            if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
{
                document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';
alert("Please attach Documents");
return false ;
}
else { return true ;}
}
</script>
```

Works very nice!

Does not work with SharePoint 2013, since it does not have "PreSaveAction"

Comment: I had used "PreSaveAction" in SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013. It works

Comment: do i need to replace idAttachmentsTable with the any id? @victor martins

Comment: @jayantkhushalani, no need, leave it as idAttachmentsTable

Comment: working fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Didnt work for me , however after making few changes in the accepted code worked fine -

```
  function PreSaveAction() {

var attach= $("#getFile")[0].value; 
if (attach && attach == null || attach.length == 0)
{
document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';

alert("Please attach Documents in the Attachment Section.It is Mandatory");
return false ;
}
else { return true ;}
}
```

where #getFile is my custom attachment column Id